# accessing 2d array using pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

In my main I have

```
  int mat[ROW][COL];
  int *p = &mat[0][0];
  minput(p, ROW, COL);
```

I'm stuck on how to make minput, because I'm supposed to initialize the 2d array with set numbers, but I just don't understand how I'm supposed to assign the numbers,

I get that m[0][0] in pointer is `*(*(m+0)+0)`, but it doesn't let me do something like `*(*(m+0)+0)=0;`,

because it gives the `invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)` error.

So basically I just want to know how to assign a number to a 2d array using pointers, if we didn't have to use pointers this would be so easy with m[2][2]=5 and whatever but I have no idea how to do this with pointers.

My prof provided a one line example of the minput function and it was just `*(m+0) = 8;`, which doesn't make sense to me, isn't that what we use for a 1d array? if that's the way to do it then does that mean I'm supposed to do something like

```
*(m+0) = 8;
*(m+1) = 1;
*(m+2) = 6;
*(m+3) = 3;
*(m+4) = 5;
*(m+5) = 7;
*(m+6) = 4;
*(m+7) = 9;
*(m+8) = 2;
```

for a 3x3 array? it doesn't seem right to me, It would be great if someone could help me out with this, pointers are very confusing to me.

EDIT: so I see that apparently the correct way to do it is the way I listed above with the 
`*(*(m+0)+0) = val`

but when I do this in my code, I get the this error:

```
error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
  *(*(m+0)+2)=6;
  ^
```

why is this the case? is the assignment wrong?

Comment: Why not pas a 2D array as a pointer to array? I.e. `f(int arr[ROW][COL])`? Anything else is just nonsense. (That is converted to `int (*)[COL]`, but you can use 2D indexing as usual). And make `p` the correct type, too!

Comment: Oh, and if that what your prof provided is really meant for a 2D array, change course. And enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them - especially when it comes to pointer and arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. You can use

```
*(m + (rowNumber*COL) + colNumber) = val
```

to access it. Basically the elements in the two-dimensional array are stored consecutively in memory, and m points to the beginning of it. Therefore you can do it in this way as an one-dimensional array. That's why we don't use something like **m, as it's not "a pointer to a pointer", even it's a two-dimensional array.

Comment: you should add that it's why we can't convert 2D Arrays into double pointers (int **), it's a common mistake.

Comment: so if I wanted to assign the value 4 to m[2][2], I would do `*(m + (2*COL) + 2) = 4` ?

Comment: That's correct. Though in your case a type cast is needed, which is *(p+...), or alternatively *((int *)mat + ...).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have 2D array declared as `arr[rows][cols]`. Then:

- `arr` points to the first subarray
- `arr + 1` points to the second subarray
- `*(*(arr+2)+3)` is equivalent to arr[2][3]

So if you want to assign a `val` to the first element of second row for example:

```
*(*(mat+1) + 0) = val;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it initialized `*((p+0) + 0) = 1;` would make `mat[0][0] = 1;`

```
*((p+0) + 1) = 2; would be mat[0][1] = 2;
*((p+1) + 0) = 3; would be mat[1][0] = 3;
```

etc..